# Hyperledger Fabric smart contract is not creating in vs code

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ibp-vscode-extension

Error populating Blockchain Explorer View: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system Expected directory: node-v64-linux-x64-glibc Found: [node-v57-linux-x64-glibc] This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system Original error: Cannot find module '/xxxx/.vscode/extensions/ibmblockchain.ibm-blockchain-platform-0.3.0/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'

Comment: Please share your code and any relevant project configuration.

Comment: What version of VSCode do you have?  You need 1.31 or above for v0.3.0 of the IBM Blockchain Extension.

Comment: Seeing the same issue with VSCode Version 1.32.1 (1.32.1), on a MAC env.   Error populating Blockchain Explorer View: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system Expected directory: node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown Found: [node-v57-darwin-x64-unknown] This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system Original error: Cannot find module '/Users/jeff/.vscode/extensions/ibmblockchain.ibm-blockchain-platform-0.3.1/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node'

Comment: Deleted the extension and also deleted all files under the ~/.vscode/extensions/ibmblockchain... directory.  Reinstalled and all is working.

Comment: Thank you guys its worked for me when im updating vs code version 1.31.1